# Tub Faucet Sticks Out From Wall. How do I fix it?

Tags: shower, faucet

My bathtub faucet sticks out from the wall so far that you can see the hole in the tile where the pipe comes out.

I am a bit perplexed on how to fix this issue.  I have an access hole on the other side and I see that the half clamp that was holding the faucet's pipe is broken.  Unfortunately, I don't have enough room to install another half clamp, which is required to be hammered in.  I've tried ones that screw into the top of the 2x4 that the pipe was attached to, but the clamp's holes wouldn't line up with the 2x4.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would cut two pieces of wood to fit, that can squeeze in there and hold the pipe where you want it. Test the fit and then put construction adhesive on them to hold them in place.

Comment: That worked like a charm.  It's been holding it in place for awhile.